# every time I run docker-compose up for WordPress the DB is empty

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml file for WordPress 
every time I run the docker-compose up the DB is empty and I need to run the 5 step install.

I don't understand what I need to do. 
I have a live Wordpress site, I clone into my local, create the yml file.

this is the yml file.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${ROOT_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_NAME}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${ROOT_PASSWORD}'

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: '${DB_USER}'
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: '${DB_NAME}'
volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

this is what I see before I run docker-compose up -d

```
local               2d6a924b957f092ea8e0f3e468ff3057021a23be6cab1cb9a468c47b1d0afc2c
local               5e098507d458788bc9393added71e8190e5919d6cfabfe90af4d26ab7aaf8ba1
local               58ee3acf025fd46403db6f0a51f0f872c4553204482e1481571da8391c3e3203
local               75bd69c4e1ebcc050035c8c8cf2b14371855ba79351bfbcdacc0181ada27ae35
local               0673aac3c62071a3e20969620cf6a44bb0c8a580fe572da376fdeafa34ec1e48
local               732ef89d1079c69696d2ac8097765dcc691706c682440a2aba0d0cf87f02039a
local               2183d9eca34bae8d12a1dd2ae0836d1261251041eec33a390f3b6c204f58bb74
local               94070855b40779105827b48a12384e08035e20fc8d2c6325b97fc4ff8f59149e
```

and this is what I see after

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               2c68ba0ccf1a44e63cea5b87160138912a279161ab62561a4e41c467aeb89018
local               2d6a924b957f092ea8e0f3e468ff3057021a23be6cab1cb9a468c47b1d0afc2c
local               5e098507d458788bc9393added71e8190e5919d6cfabfe90af4d26ab7aaf8ba1
local               58ee3acf025fd46403db6f0a51f0f872c4553204482e1481571da8391c3e3203
local               75bd69c4e1ebcc050035c8c8cf2b14371855ba79351bfbcdacc0181ada27ae35
local               0673aac3c62071a3e20969620cf6a44bb0c8a580fe572da376fdeafa34ec1e48
local               732ef89d1079c69696d2ac8097765dcc691706c682440a2aba0d0cf87f02039a
local               2183d9eca34bae8d12a1dd2ae0836d1261251041eec33a390f3b6c204f58bb74
local               94070855b40779105827b48a12384e08035e20fc8d2c6325b97fc4ff8f59149e
local               bz_research_db_data
```

Comment: Try volumes: db_data: driver: local instead of your volumes: db_data: {}. That's the only part that looks unusual to me but honestly I don't see why it shouldn't be working. Also surprised to see you aren't mapping port 3306:3306.

Comment: what do you mean not mapping port 3306:3306?

Comment: Map your local computers port 3306 to use your db containers 3306 port, so that you can access your database from your local machine by just using localhost as the address

Comment: Oh OK. 
BTW, when I wrote 
    db_data: driver: local
and tried to run docker compose up I got this error 
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

Comment: There should be a breakline after the colons, I just cant symbolise that in comments. Just a yaml structure error

Comment: OK now it works but still, I got the 5 steps install :(
I update the post with the updated yml file.

Comment: How do you stop your project (show the entire command you run)? Does your current directory name, or compose project name, change? What does `docker volume ls` show before and after you stop your project?

Comment: The `driver: local` is the default, it is not needed. And publishing port 3306 gives people outside of your host access to the DB, not needed when you only access the DB through other containers, rather it creates a security risk.

Comment: I just use `docker-compose down` to take down my containers. The project directory is different for different devs, but apart from that doesn't change. My docker volume ls doesn't change before and after launching. Yeah driver local is default, but I couldn't see anything else that was different to mine, and yes publishing the port does do that, I didn't release you didn't want the db to be accessible from outside the container, if there are issues with it being able to connect is very helpful.

Comment: so I run the command ```docker-compose down --volume```. 
the name of the project/folder doesn't change (I think). how can I check the name? I'm sorry I'm new with this docker world :) 
I edit the post with the docker volume ls.

Comment: @MaorBar fyi the `bz_research` is from your directory. That's referred to as the compose project name, and it's possible to change it (there are variables and flags that docker-compose uses, but usually it defaults to the directory name). It doesn't appear to be relevant for this specific issue, however changing it would have created a new/empty named volume for the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `docker-compose down --volume` has the following behavior from `docker-compose down --help`:

```
Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images
created by `up`.

By default, the only things removed are:

- Containers for services defined in the Compose file
- Networks defined in the `networks` section of the Compose file
- The default network, if one is used

Networks and volumes defined as `external` are never removed.

...

    -v, --volumes           Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes`
                            section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                            attached to containers.
```

So with the `--volumes` arg, you are intentionally deleting the `bz_research_db_data` volume, as you can see in your output.

The solution is to just run `docker-compose down` instead, which will leave the named volumes behind for later reuse.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.